# XAML call TabItem Unload event programmatically

Tags: xaml

I'm quite new to XAML so I'm hoping this to be a very simple question.

My main window has a TabControl and on certain cases, I would like to call the Unload event on a certain Tab.

The MainView xaml looks like this:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:NameSpace.Project1.Views"  x:Class="NameSpace.Project1.Views.MainWindow"            
        Width="500" Height="500"
        Title="Hello World">

    <Grid>
        <TabControl x:Name="MyTabs" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <TabItem Header="Live" Name="ChildView">
                <Views:ChildView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Playback" Name="OtherView">
                <Views:OtherView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

QUESTION:
On Close of the Application, I'm getting an OnExit event on the App.xaml.cs code, and there I wanted to make sure the ChildView Tab calls its Unload event.

I tried to programmatically call **MyTabs.SelectedItem** or **MyTabs.SelectedIndex** or **OtherTab.IsVisible = true** but none fire up the Unload event of the ChildView.

If I click on the OtherView tab, that event fires.

How do I call it programmatically??
Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: You do know that you can do this in your `xaml`, just use `EventTriggers` or `DataTriggers`- using `Enter` and `Exit Action`s and do the logic there using converters. [link](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html) to the converters and [Enter and Exit Actions](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-animations-enteractions-exitactions/). HTH

Comment: @XAMlMAX I'm not clear what you mean by "do the logic there". Is that adding the Unloaded="name of proc to unload" on the XMAL? The application is killed by a Windows WM_ event and so only the App.xaml.cs captures that. So from the App.xaml.cs on the OnExit call, I need to make sure I call the Unloaded of the ChildView. Else it does not get called. When I unload the ChildView, I need to clear some resources on external DLLs so I don't think that logic is something I can write inside the Xaml. I just need to access the TabItem and call Unload or something that triggers that event from App.cs

Comment: So in my understanding you want to clear the resources from the `TabItem`? If so, do you really need to do it on the `Unload` Event? Surely if you are managing when the application is closing you could resolve them then and there, unless of course it's not that simple.

Comment: Yes I just need to clear resources. I'm trying to use the TabItem, just because I cannot find a way to get an "instance" of the view from the main app.xaml.cs. The freeing of the resources on that specific view is in a public method, so I could call it from the app.xaml.cs OnExit event, if I could get an instance of it. Be aware that I'm totally a newbie at XMAL :)